# Xpath following siblings until another sibling

Tags: python, xpath

I'm new to using Xpath. I'm trying to parse some data in Python using Xpath.

Parsing the following HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="DT">29-04-14</td>
        <td class="Regio">Text</td>
        <td class="Md">Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="SomeClass">Some other text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="SomeOtherClass">Some more text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="DT">22-04-14</td>
        <td class="Regio">Text</td>
        <td class="Md">Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="OmsAm">more text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="DT">30-04-14</td>
        <td class="Regio">Text</td>
        <td class="Md">Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="OmsBr">Some other Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="OmsBr">More Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="OmsBr">Some different text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I need all `<td>` in following siblings `<tr>` after a `<tr>` with some values in his `<td>`s, but *until* the next `<tr>` with some values in all `<td>`s.

E.g. assuming my current position is the first `<tr>`, I would need these table cells:

```
    <td class="SomeClass">Some other text</td>
    <td class="SomeOtherClass">Some more text</td>
```

Assuming my current position is the table row 4

```
<tr>
    <td class="DT">22-04-14</td>
    <td class="Regio">Text</td>
    <td class="Md">Text</td>
</tr>
```

I would only need

```
    <td class="OmsAm">more text</td>
```

This is the Xpath I'm using to get all sibling `<tr>`, but it gets me *all* follinwg siblings, and not until the sibling it should stop: `./following-sibling::tr/td[1][not(text()[1])]/..`

I think I have to implement the Kayesian method, but I don't understand this in my case. Any help would be really apreciated!

Comment: I seriously don't get `I need all <td> in following siblings <tr> after a <tr> with some values in his <td>s, but until the next <tr> with some values in all <td>s.`

Comment: Please show your Python code. An XPath expression that solves this problem will be long-winded. Rather, you should write a relatively simple XPath expression and then process the results with Python.

Comment: Do you want to segment the  `<tr>`s with `<td class="DT">` as boundaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be misinterpreting the question, but if, for each `<tr><td class="DT">xx-xx-xx</td>`, you want all `<tr>` after it, and before the next `<tr><td class="DT">xx-xx-xx</td>`, one pattern is to loop on these "boundary" `<tr><td class="DT">xx-xx-xx</td>` elements, and selecting following sibling rows with a condition on how many "boundaries" are found before.

Let's use `lxml` to illustrate. First, we create a document from your sample input:

```
>>> import lxml.html
>>> t = '''<table>
...     <tr>
...         <td class="DT">29-04-14</td>
...         <td class="Regio">Text</td>
...         <td class="Md">Text</td>
...     </tr>
...     <tr>
...         <td></td>
...         <td></td>
...         <td class="SomeClass">Some other text</td>
...     </tr>
...     <tr>
...         <td></td>
...         <td></td>
...         <td class="SomeOtherClass">Some more text</td>
...     </tr>
...     <tr>
...         <td class="DT">22-04-14</td>
...         <td class="Regio">Text</td>
...         <td class="Md">Text</td>
...     </tr>
...     <tr>
...         <td></td>
...         <td></td>
...         <td class="OmsAm">more text</td>
...     </tr>
...     <tr>
...         <td class="DT">30-04-14</td>
...         <td class="Regio">Text</td>
...         <td class="Md">Text</td>
...     </tr>
...     <tr>
...         <td></td>
...         <td></td>
...         <td class="OmsBr">Some other Text</td>
...     </tr>
...     <tr>
...         <td></td>
...         <td></td>
...         <td class="OmsBr">More Text</td>
...     </tr>
...     <tr>
...         <td></td>
...         <td></td>
...         <td class="OmsBr">Some different text</td>
...     </tr>
... </table>'''
>>> doc = lxml.html.fromstring(t)
```

Now, let's count these `<tr><td class="DT">xx-xx-xx</td>`:

```
>>> doc.xpath('//table/tr[td/@class="DT"]')
[<Element tr at 0x7f948ab00548>, <Element tr at 0x7f948ab005e8>, <Element tr at 0x7f948ab00638>]
>>> doc.xpath('count(//table/tr[td/@class="DT"])')
3.0
>>> list(enumerate(doc.xpath('//table/tr[td/@class="DT"]'), start=1))
[(1, <Element tr at 0x7f948ab00548>), (2, <Element tr at 0x7f948ab005e8>), (3, <Element tr at 0x7f948ab00638>)]
```

We can loop on these rows and select the rows that come after in the document (we'll select text nodes to "see" which row these are:

```
>>> for cnt, row in enumerate(doc.xpath('//table/tr[td/@class="DT"]'), start=1):
...     print( row.xpath('./following-sibling::tr/td/text()') )
... 
['Some other text', 'Some more text', '22-04-14', 'Text', 'Text', 'more text', '30-04-14', 'Text', 'Text', 'Some other Text', 'More Text', 'Some different text']
['more text', '30-04-14', 'Text', 'Text', 'Some other Text', 'More Text', 'Some different text']
['Some other Text', 'More Text', 'Some different text']
```

We're selecting too many rows in each iteration, all the rows until the end of the `<table>`. We need an additional "end" condition for following rows.

We're counting the `tr[td/@class="DT"]` in the loop, so we can check how many preceding `tr[td/@class="DT"]` each row has:

For the 1st set:

```
row.xpath('./following-sibling::tr[count(./preceding-sibling::tr[td/@class="DT"])=1]
```

For the 2nd:

```
row.xpath('./following-sibling::tr[count(./preceding-sibling::tr[td/@class="DT"])=2]
```

etc.

So, in the loop, we can use the current count with an XPath variable with lxml ([an underrated XPath feature supported by lxml](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html)):

```
>>> for cnt, row in enumerate(doc.xpath('//table/tr[td/@class="DT"]'), start=1):
...     print( row.xpath('./following-sibling::tr[count(./preceding-sibling::tr[td/@class="DT"])=$count]', count=cnt) )
... 
[<Element tr at 0x7f948ab00548>, <Element tr at 0x7f948ab005e8>, <Element tr at 0x7f948ec02f98>]
[<Element tr at 0x7f948ab00548>, <Element tr at 0x7f948ab00638>]
[<Element tr at 0x7f948ab00548>, <Element tr at 0x7f948ab005e8>, <Element tr at 0x7f948ab00688>]
>>>
```

Hm, we're selecting 1 row too much in each iteration.

That's because `<tr><td class="DT">30-04-14</td>` also has 1 preceding `<tr><td class="DT">`

We can add an extra predicate for selecting rows that do NOT have a `<td class="DT">`

```
>>> for cnt, row in enumerate(doc.xpath('//table/tr[td/@class="DT"]'), start=1):
...     print( row.xpath('''
...         ./following-sibling::tr[count(./preceding-sibling::tr[td/@class="DT"])=$count]
...                                [not(td/@class="DT")]''', count=cnt) )
... 
[<Element tr at 0x7f948ab00548>, <Element tr at 0x7f948ab005e8>]
[<Element tr at 0x7f948ab00548>]
[<Element tr at 0x7f948ab00548>, <Element tr at 0x7f948ab005e8>, <Element tr at 0x7f948ab00688>]
>>>
```

The number of results per iteration looks right.
Let's finally check using text nodes:

```
>>> for cnt, row in enumerate(doc.xpath('//table/tr[td/@class="DT"]'), start=1):
...     print( row.xpath('''
...         ./following-sibling::tr[count(./preceding-sibling::tr[td/@class="DT"])=$count]
...                                [not(td/@class="DT")]
...             /td/text()''', count=cnt) )
... 
['Some other text', 'Some more text']
['more text']
['Some other Text', 'More Text', 'Some different text']
>>>
```

Comment: Wow, great explanation and works perfect! Thanks a lot!

Comment: like a perfect example of why sometimes using substr and strpos is way better than xpath